# C# linq: join with or condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to join 2 tables with an or condition. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var dos = from d in dc.Dos
            join c in dc.Clis on (d.clid = c.id or d.clid is null)
            select new { id = d.id, clid = d.clid, cliname = c.Name }
```

But I receive syntax errors. How can I fix it? What I want is to receive the rows with d.clid = c.id and the rows with d.clid = null

Comment: "But I receive syntax errors" Which?

Comment: `join c in dc.Clis on (d.clid = c.id or d.clid is null)` => it should be `join c in dc.Clis on d.clid equals c.id where d.clid == null`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto this will bring only the rows with d.clid == null.